# Convert a class to its superclass

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class

First, I created some classes like this:

```
class superClass {
}

class class1: superClass {
    var a:Int = 0
}

class class2: superClass {
    var b:Int = 0
}
```

And I constructed an array to store them:

```
var myClasses:[superClass] = []
```

I added something to the array in this way:

```
let newClass = class1()
newClass.a = 1
myClasses.append(newClass)
```

And:

```
let newClass = class2()
newClass.b = 2
myClasses.append(newClass)
```

Now I wanna check the array like this:

```
for eachObject in myClasses {
    // code...
}
```

I want to classify **eachObject** and figure out which class it belongs to.

If it belongs to class1, I need to print the value of **eachObject.a**

Is there a way to make it? Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
for eachObject in myClasses {

    if let obj = eachObject as?  class1 {
        // class1 type object
    } else {
       // class2  type object    
   }    
}
```

another way to check object type using Use the type check operator `is`

```
for eachObject in myClasses {

    if eachObject is  class1 {
        // class1 type object
    } else if eachObject is class2 {
        // class2  type object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want figure out `class1`, you can do like this:

```
for case let eachObject as class1 in myClasses {
    print(eachObject.a)
}
```